# Call a Javascript function from aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, onclick

Code from aspx.cs:

```
.......
button.OnClientClick = "onButtonClick(this)";
.....
```

Function in Javascript(written in the aspx file):

```
<script> 
        function onButtonClick(event) {
           ....
        }
</script>
```

The "program" didn't even get to the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you calling your button.OnClientClick assignment? If it is in the page load or a button click event, it should work. If you are calling it in an ajax method, the button may be be rendered after the assignment, so maybe that's your problem.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.OnClientClick = "clicky(this)";
}
```

On .aspx page, just before the closing  tag:

```
<script>
   function clicky(e) {
      alert("click");
   }
</script>
```

You should be able to see onclick="clicky(this)"; when you inspect the element in the Chrome developer tools when you run the page.

Answer (score 0):

Well its redundant to call a JavaScript with a asp button when you can always just use the on click method with a normal html button.

```
 <button onclick="onButtonClick()">Click me</button>
```

However here is how you can do it with the following ways

```
Response.write("<script type=""text/javascript"">onButtonClick();</script>")

// OR
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:onButtonClick(); ", true);
// OR 
string name = "onButtonClick()";
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(string), "Key", name, true);
// OR    
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), name, false);
```

Comment: Might want to use scriptManager then.

Comment: agree with @John. the page will need a script manager `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>` as seen: http://javascriptshorts.com/JavaScript-call-a-javascript-code-block-from-aspx-page-code-behind-page